PayU Checkout Pro in android
I am trying on integrate PayU Checkout Pro on Android but with the code below, the check out page loads up shows "Processing" and then closes by itself in a second.
As of now I am generating hash locally for testing.
This is code initiated when i click on "MAKE PAYMENT" button -
        HashGenerator hashGenerator;
        PayUPaymentParams payUPaymentParams;

        hashGenerator = new HashGenerator();
        hashGenerator.setTxnid(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        hashGenerator.setAmount("1.00");
        hashGenerator.setProductinfo("Macbook Pro");
        hashGenerator.setFirstname("John");
        hashGenerator.setEmail("john@gmail.com");
        hashGenerator.setPhone("9999999999");

        PayUPaymentParams.Builder builder = new PayUPaymentParams.Builder();
        builder.setAmount(hashGenerator.getAmount())
                .setIsProduction(true)
                .setProductInfo(hashGenerator.getProductinfo())
                .setKey(hashGenerator.getKey())
                .setTransactionId(hashGenerator.getTxnid())
                .setFirstName(hashGenerator.getFirstname())
                .setEmail(hashGenerator.getEmail())
                .setPhone(hashGenerator.getPhone())
                .setSurl("https://cbjs.payu.in/sdk/success")
                .setFurl("https://cbjs.payu.in/sdk/failure");
        payUPaymentParams = builder.build();

        PayUCheckoutPro.open(
                this,
                payUPaymentParams,
                new PayUCheckoutProListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPaymentSuccess(Object response) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPaymentFailure(Object response) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPaymentCancel(boolean isTxnInitiated) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(ErrorResponse errorResponse) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void setWebViewProperties(@Nullable WebView webView, @Nullable Object o) {
                        //For setting webview properties, if any. Check Customized Integration section for more details on this
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void generateHash(HashMap<String,String> valueMap, PayUHashGenerationListener hashGenerationListener) {
                        String hashName = valueMap.get(PayUCheckoutProConstants.CP_HASH_NAME);
                        String hashData = valueMap.get(PayUCheckoutProConstants.CP_HASH_STRING);
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(hashName) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(hashData)) {
                            //Do not generate hash from local, it needs to be calculated from server side only. Here, hashString contains hash created from your server side.
                            String hash = hashGenerator.generateHash();
                            Log.d("ABCDE", "HASH: "+hash);
                            HashMap dataMap = new HashMap();
                            dataMap.put(hashName, hash);
                            hashGenerationListener.onHashGenerated(dataMap);
                        }
                    }
                }
        );


Here is code for HashGenerator class which I am using just for convenience -
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class HashGenerator {

    private String txnid;
    private String amount;
    private String productinfo;
    private String firstname;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private final String key = "mykey";
    private final String salt = "mysalt";

    public HashGenerator() {
    }

    public String generateHash() {
        String input = key + "|" + txnid + "|" + amount + "|" + productinfo + "|" + firstname + "|" + email + "|||||||||||" + salt;
        return sha512(input.toLowerCase());
    }

    private static String sha512(String input) {
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
            byte[] hashBytes = md.digest(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte b : hashBytes) {
                sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public String getTxnid() {
        return txnid;
    }
    public void setTxnid(String txnid) {
        this.txnid = txnid;
    }
    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    public String getProductinfo() {
        return productinfo;
    }
    public void setProductinfo(String productinfo) {
        this.productinfo = productinfo;
    }
    public String getSalt() {
        return "QcOUKmTPLYigvaniwehruhFAGukJgZ6u";
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}

Steps taken till now -

Key and Salt used are correct.
The line - Log.d("ABCDE", "HASH: "+hash); is generating the same hash string 3 times when I click on "MAKE PAYMENT" button.

Possible issue - I checked with PayU support. According to them we have to generate multiple hashes in SDK to land on checkout page.
How do I achieve that ? or is there any other issue ?

Any suggestions ?
